# python script to connect to remote server and count the number of files

Tags: python, linux, paramiko

I have a requirement to get the number of files in the remote server thru Python.I have used the paramiko module and wrote the below script. The linux command when running in the terminal is giving me the desired output whereas when executing from Python is giving me the output as [u'0\n'].Any help is highly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import paramiko
client=paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('hostname', username='username')
grepCommand="ssh  username@hostname 'find /usr/local/somefolder1/somefolder2 -type f   -exec ls  {} \;'|wc -l"
stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command(grepCommand)
data=stdout.readlines()
print data
client.close()
```

Comment: it gives you right result but in unicode just run for i in data ; print(i.encode('ascii','replace'))

Comment: that said first part of grepCommand is plain wrong, you're already connected to host via paramiko so it's pointless to connect via ssh once more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the paramiko library is already making the ssh connection for you, you don't need to execute ssh in your remote command.  Also it seems that you are piping the output locally into `wc`.. something you can't do here because with paramiko you aren't using a local shell.  So:

Your `grepCommand` should be exactly what would work if you were to execute it in a shell on the remote machine.

eg:

```
 find /etc -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: Much appreciated , modified the code as per the recommendations but now getting the value as 0 whereas there are 21 files in the remote server.
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import paramiko
client=paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('hostname', username='username')
grepCommand="'find /usr/local/somefolder1/somefolder2 -type f   -exec ls  {} \;'|wc -l"
stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command(grepCommand)
data=stdout.readlines()
for i in data:
        print(i.encode('ascii','replace'))
client.close()

Comment: Test whatever command you are running  by logging into the remote machine interactively and running it there.

Comment: Also, are you absolutely sure that the user you are logging in as has rx permissions on the directory?  And that your connection is successful?  Check the auth/sshd logs on the remote to make sure you're connecting

Comment: Your command is still structured as if you had both a remote and local shell which you don't have.  Your command is far more complicated than it needs to be.. look at the example command I put in my answer.

Comment: i reran the same command in the terminal and below are the results
[arun@pstools ~]$ ssh  username@hostname 'find /usr/local/somefolder1/somefolder2 -type f   -exec ls  {} \;'|wc -l
21
[arun@pstools ~]$ python gretl.py
0
The second is the python execution result wheras the first one is the linux command execution result

Comment: No.. you are still running the command in your local shell.. AND ssh.  That is not what I'm saying.  SSH to the remote box.. without any command.  Get yourself into a shell there.  Then figure out JUST the command you need to execute remotely to get the answer you want.. which will probably look a lot like the command I put in my answer.  Look at my answer.

Comment: you are right , when ssh to remote box it gave me the result as 0.
i will try to figure out the exact command in  the remote box now.thanks

Comment: Great!  Glad I could help.. accept my answer please, thanks!

Comment: Hi,In the same find command how can i pass the date value.the reason for the question is one of the folder(somfolder2) is created each day with the format 20170712_060013
find /usr/local/somefolder1/somefolder2 -type f   -exec ls  {} \;'|wc -l
and the python variable which accepts the date value is not converting into actual  date in the remote server.
grepCommand='find /usr/local/somefolder1/${date}_* -type f  |wc -l'